# Encoding header for ACCEPT and specifying cache validator for Blob URLs

Tags: php, nginx, blob, fpm

How do I define `Accept` encoding headers and cache validator for URLs starting with BLOB?

E.g. https://www.xxxx.com/dd403999-770f-49ea-9a97-7d40d20e88eb

Server: nginx, php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

If your Web service is NGINX, it is enough to have the file available at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. Edit yourself and enter the following command.

gzip_vary on